# Is there any way around the scope issue? Writing a generic method to add listeners to JRadioButtonMenuItems

Tags: java, local-variables

I'm writing the same code over and over, because when I write it as it's own method I get the scope issue, "Local variable ... defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final". Is there any way around this, other than just writing the code over and over as I have been doing?

This works:

```
        monochromeOption.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameboard.monochromeColor = cO;
                gameboard.monochromeColor_temp = cO;
                gameboard.repaint();
            }
        });
        monochromeOption.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                gameboard.monochromeColor_temp = gameboard.monochromeColor;
                gameboard.monochromeColor = cO;
                gameboard.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                gameboard.monochromeColor = gameboard.monochromeColor_temp;
                gameboard.repaint();
            }
        });
```

This doesn't:

```
private static <T> void addRadioListenersWithMouseOver(NerdChessGameboard board, JRadioButtonMenuItem button, T toAssign, T gameboardT, T gameboardT_temp) {
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gameboardT = toAssign;
            gameboardT_temp = toAssign;
            board.repaint();
        }
    });
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            gameboardT_temp = gameboardT;
            gameboardT = toAssign;
            board.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            gameboardT = gameboardT_temp;
            board.repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

It's the scope issue, requiring a variable to final or effectively final, and I always just code around it, but this time it's really... ugly. I've copy-pasted the same piece of code a dozen times now, and I just don't see any reason for this. I get that it's just the way the JVM works, that it's doing this to avoid bigger errors in other situations. But in this situation it makes no sense and I want a way around it! Lol. Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or does everyone that uses Java just code around this issue in exchange for use of the other benefits of Java?

Comment: What is the problem in using the `final` keyword?

Comment: @Progman, check their code out!

Comment: Both the answers here were good, but the real answer turned out to be that I am dumb. I got the references and objects confused in my head somehow, and was thinking I could pass references. That's what gameboard.monochromeColor is in the original, the reference I am assigning an object to. As far as I know, there's no way to pass references in Java? Let me know if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or does everyone that uses Java just code around this issue in exchange for use of the other benefits of Java?"*

The topic of *[Java inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)* will typically cover the issue you're describing.

Since you're creating an *[anonymous-class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)* within your *button* object, *[encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))* this resource.

There is more than one way to organize the data, here is a basic example.

```java
class NerdChessGameboard extends JComponent {
    class Example<T> extends JRadioButtonMenuItem implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
        T toAssign, gameboardT, gameboardT_temp;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gameboardT = toAssign;
            gameboardT_temp = toAssign;
            NerdChessGameboard.this.repaint();
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            gameboardT_temp = gameboardT;
            gameboardT = toAssign;
            NerdChessGameboard.this.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            gameboardT = gameboardT_temp;
            NerdChessGameboard.this.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea. I actually had something just like this (though non-generic) awhile back for other reasons but got rid of it when I thought it wasn't useful, totally spaced on it. Will give it another try

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue:

```
private static <T> void addRadioListenersWithMouseOver(NerdChessGameboard board, JRadioButtonMenuItem button, T toAssign, T gameboardT, T gameboardT_temp) {
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            gameboardT = toAssign; // right here
```

The issue is that toAssign is a method (ie stack) variable. When `actionPerformed` is called, this variable will no longer be on the stack, so actionPerformed cannot reference it.

BUT...

adding the final keyword to it, the value passed to addRadioListenersW... will automatically be set in the listener, rather than being linked when actionPerformed is called

Comment: Adding the "final" keyword where? To the variables used in the call?